# How do i clear data from a C++ structured array?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if there is a way to clear memory/data that is inputted in a structured array?

```cpp
struct order{
int qtyData;
double priceOrder;
string nameOrder;
}food[20];
//Clear the Arrays <-- Error!!!
fill_n(food[20].qtyData, 20, 0);
fill_n(food[20].priceOrder, 20, 0.00);
fill_n(food[20].nameOrder, 20, "");
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.  `std::vector` provides member function that make this easy.

Comment: Use a simple `for()` loop for all instances of the array, clear each struct-element.

Comment: If the `struct` didn't have that `string` member, then you could use `std::memset()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I understand you question correctly, but you can
assign a complete struct at once, like so:

```cpp
    std::fill_n(std::begin(food), 20, order{0, 0.0, ""});
```

This overrides 20 entries in the array `food` with `order{0, 0.0, ""}`,
starting from the beginning.

If you use `std::fill` instead, you don't have to repeat the size like this:

```cpp
    std::fill(std::begin(food), std::end(food), order{0, 0.0, ""});
```

which fills all elements, whatever the size of the array.

Comment: I'll try it out

Comment: it works but it does not null it, like empty it for what i am doing is to print out a receipt  to cout a the name, quantity and price which is in the array. When i looped it it prints out a empty space follow by 0 and 0.00

Comment: Its ok, i found the solution to my own problem, your answer is very helpful thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.

First, [arrays are 0 based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892862/why-array-index-start-from-0). That means that the first element is `0`, and the last one (in your case) is `19`. There is no `20`. Consequently, [referring to `food[20]` is undefined behavior](https://www.viva64.com/en/t/0071/), which [allows your program to do literally anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen), although the most likely is probably your program crashing.

The second problem with your code is that [`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) looks for the first object you want filled, not the last. That means, you want `food[0]`, not `food[20]`:

```
fill_n(food[0].qtyData, 20, 0);
fill_n(food[0].priceOrder, 20, 0.00);
fill_n(food[0].nameOrder, 20, "");
```

Something like that should work, although--full disclosure--it is untested. But it should be in the general ballpark of what you need.

The only other thing that *I* see that could be a problem is by calling something like `food[0].qtyData`, `std::fill_n()` may not work like you would think it would, since `qtyData` is an `int`. I'm not familiar enough with `std::fill_n()`, but I think it might only clear the next 20 `int`s, not the next 20 `qtyData`s. You may need the full struct like this instead:

```
fill_n(food[0], 20, 0);
```

Although, again, this is still untested.

Comment: Can you explain which value will be, after `fill_n` usage at `food[15].qtyData`? And at  `food[15].nameOrder`?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm not too familiar with `fill_n()`. I can merely make an educated guess, which is that it'd treat the memory stored at `food` as an array of `int`s, which would basically bleed into the memory stored in other parts of the struct. But I'm not 100% positive.