# Problem with read data from file, a simple code in C language

Tags: c

I write a simple code to read data from texts file.
It is showed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* FP0 ;
    FILE* FP1 ;

    int i, j ;
    int NPOINTS ;

    FP0= fopen("G:\\DATA\\data0.text","r");

    fscanf(FP0,"%d", &NPOINTS); 

    fclose(FP0);

    float COORDINATOFPOINTS[NPOINTS][2] ;

    FP1= fopen("G:\\DATA\\data1.text","r"); 

    for (i = 1; i<NPOINTS+1; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 1; j<3; ++j)
        {
            fscanf(FP1,"%f", &COORDINATOFPOINTS[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    fclose(FP1);

    printf("%d",NPOINTS); 

    for (i = 1; i<NPOINTS+1; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 1; j<3; ++j) 
        {
            printf("%f", COORDINATOFPOINTS[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, it shows:0

Can someone explain why and what is wrong?

Comment: For a start read the manual pages for `fopen` and `fscanf`. They return a value that needs to be checked. Some return values denote an error

Comment: Indent your code properly before posting

Comment: @EdHeal How this return value leads us to debug the code?

Comment: Because the return value tells you if the function call was successful or not

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as "C/C++". They are different langugages.

Comment: You are accessing your arrays out of bounds. indices start at 0.

Comment: @klutt Thanks for your comment. It shows error (returned value= -1) about first read (NPOINTS). I want to read an integer value (like 3) from a file and I don't know why it shows the error.

Comment: When it comes to arrays, study this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892862/why-array-index-start-from-0

Comment: Also, learn how to create a [mre]

Comment: @klutt first "fscanf" showed error ( fscanf(FP0,"%d", &NPOINTS) ).

Comment: Repeated, even if file Io operations are successful. **You are accessing your arrays out of bounds** . C is zero-based indexing. An array of N elements allows indexes in 0..(N-1) inclusively. Your loops index 1..N. They breach the top end, and in so doing invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What is the content of your file? And did you add checks for `fopen` as well?

Comment: @Gerhardh Number 3. No, I have a problem with the format of "FP0" for "printf" command.

Comment: You don't print `FP0`. As you don't get more output, you don't enter the loop which means your problem is not related to `printf`. Your file content is only `3` on the very first line or are there empty lines before?

Comment: @Gerhardh I think my problem in "fscanf" command. My first "fscanf" read a value from a text file. In that text file, there is just number 3. You said: "did you add checks for fopen as well?" and I said:"No, I have a problem with the format of "FP0" for "printf" command"

Comment: Your `scanf` returns -1 which indicates an error. This could be caused by not finding an integer of by feeding a `NULL` pointer into it. Which is why you should check result of `fopen` as mentioned by Ed Heal in the first commnt. Therefore: If you didn't add a check yet, why not? Please do it now.

Comment: @NULL - It is a good idea to use more meaningful variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the simplicity of the answer, since I can not mention, I write it here:

The first problem is about arrays out of bounds due to zero-based indexing of C.

The second problem is referred to the prefix of a text file.  There is no ".text" prefix. You must change it to ".txt".

The third problem (as I find your code) is about read data from a text file in line by line approach. You can add "\n" for indicating to the pointer that it must go to the next line.

Comment: .text is definitely not a prefix since it comes LAST in the file name and nothing is preventing a file from having the extension .text instead of .txt, even if this could potentially be the source for problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems your answer is correct but when I print the data, it just prints the last two arrays. What could be wrong?

Comment: @NULL A lot of things. As I've said, you have not provided a [mre]

Comment: I agree with @klutt. But I recommend you use the same loop for printing the data as for reading it. Then try to change it and find the logic of the error.

Comment: @ALIN Thanks for the recommendation.